Is the equation for the torque required correct?
Hey guys, I am working on a project in which 2 blades kept at an angle is used to cut stem of a plant. Rollers are used to pinch and force the stem towards the intersecting point of the blades. Lets assume force F is required for shearing of the stem. And the angle between the blades is 2 theta. The reaction R is provided by the blades perpendicular to the cutting edge. Resolving the forces and assuming static equilibrium just before shearing, I formulated the equation shown in the image. From the equation, we can see that as theta increases, the torque required also increases, i.e., Torque is directly proportional to theta. I want to know if the formulation is correct and kindly correct me if there is an error.


How does the stem diameter  exactly match the distance between the rollers? Are they adjustable? I would think that the torque required would depend on the match/mismatch of the distance between the rollers and the diameter of the stem.

Yes, your calculation is correct. However, a smaller angle indicates a greater distance from the fulcrum, longer blades, and less leverage on the blades, resulting in a heavier mechanism. Cutting blades in the industry are orthogonal to the work!

@AJN , since the rollers are used to pinch the stem, so radius of the stem becomes very small. hence I took the radius of the roller

@kamran, thank you for the reply.
